# Python Subprocess Module PIPE Lines

Tags: python, pipe, subprocess

What do you know guys about PIPE Lines under Python Subprocess Module.?

Here is an example:

code 1:

```
from subprocess import *
output = Popen("ls")
```

code 2

```
from subprocess import *
output = Popen("ls", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
```

What is the different between the 2 codes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Lots of stuff. Do you have a question in particular?

Comment: Please, check out the question again, i made some modifications

Comment: Check out the documentation at `python.org`. It explains the possible arguments to the `Popen()` constructor very well... Or, you could just type `help(subprocess.Popen)` into an interactive Python session... Not quite as verbose, but usually pretty good as well...

Comment: I do know how to use Subprocess very well, what i need to know is the concept, We usually use PIPE with subprocess when we want to send the stdout over sockets, and without PIPEs the stdout cannot be sent

Comment: @Boumediene_Kaddour: here's [code example that shows how to send output over sockets **without** PIPEs on a POSIX system.](https://gist.github.com/zed/7454768)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first code, `output` will be a object containing the result of `ls` command on the current directory.

In your second code, you are piping the `stdout` of the `ls` command, here you have taken the `stdin` mentioning just `PIPE` which is wrong as you have not mention any object from which you are taking `stdin`.

Your second code could be better in this form:

```
from subprocess import *
output = Popen(["ls"], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Here i have used the `communicate` method of `subprocess` to take the `stdout` (and `stderr`) sent via piping at its `stdin`. It returns a tuple of `(stdout, stderr)` but we are interested in `stdout` (index 0) only so i have used `communicate()[0]`.

Comment: it is incorrect. In both cases the inproperly named `"output"` is a `Popen` object. It does not contain the result (output) of `ls` command. In the first case, `ls`' output goes whereever the parent's (`python`) stdout points (e.g., to the terminal). In the second case, (part of) `ls` output is buffered in `output.stdout` object.